# Read JSON with Android

Tags: android, json, exception

I'm trying to read a JSON from a server but not'm getting

```
  public JSONObject getJSON(){ 
  JSONObject jsonObject = null;
  try{
    // Create a new HTTP Client
    DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Setup the get request
    HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("URL");

    // Execute the request in the client
    HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
    // Grab the response
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new                          
        InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().
        getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String json = reader.readLine();

    // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

} catch(Exception e){
    // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return jsonObject;
```

}
Exception:

```
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I'm using tags permission to use internet in XML Android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that with `AsyncTask` since network mustnt be on main thread